# Problem on my database by launching it on Visual Studio Code

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-code, wamp

I have a problem to put my database that I created in SQL when I insert it on Visual Studio Code when I was at school I had the same problem and so I tried to insert one that our teacher gave us and then after the one I created and finally it worked but at home I tried and impossible I got this error message if someone is why?

```
2023-07-01 19:16:04 Creating MySQL connection for 1688157436326_tree
2023-07-01 19:16:09 Executing: C:\Users\matte\.dbclient\dependency\mysql\mysql.exe -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root --default-character-set=utf8 undefined <"c:\Users\matte\Desktop\Fourni_DWEB-S6Ex1.sql"
2023-07-01 19:16:09 Executing: C:\Users\matte\.dbclient\dependency\mysql\mysql.exe -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root --default-character-set=utf8 undefined <"c:\Users\matte\Desktop\Fourni_DWEB-S6Ex1.sql"
Command failed: C:\Users\matte\.dbclient\dependency\mysql\mysql.exe -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root --default-character-set=utf8 undefined <"c:\Users\matte\Desktop\Fourni_DWEB-S6Ex1.sql"
ERROR 1049 (42000): Base 'undefined' inconnue
```

I tried on another computer at home and still not working.

Comment: Why did you tag this question with `sql-server` when your error message is for MySQL?

Comment: The error code `ERROR 1049 (42000)` indicates "unknown database" - and your log shows you passing "`undefined`" (literally) as the database name - so you've got a bug in your setup script you should fix.

Comment: If I have what you told me, I'll show you the beginning of my database, but it was still working fine. Several people in my class have had this problem. I directly use the function in visual studio code with mySQL extension DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS hhva_matteosbs; CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS hhva_matteosbs; USE hhva_matteosbs; Here is the beginning of my table

Comment: You're including all sorts of irrelevant stuff. like where your sql files are stored. What will help  the community help you is the actual sql statement that fails. I suspect if you do identify that one, you will even solve it yourself very likely :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't a have database in your Mysql or the database name is wrong, you can do the next:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydatabasename;
USE mydatabasename;
```

And:

```
mysql -uroot –pmypassword < mydatabase.sql
```

And the tag is not sql-server

Comment: If I have what you told me, I'll show you the beginning of my database, but it was still working fine. Several people in my class have had this problem. I directly use the function in visual studio code with mySQL extension                                   
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS hhva_matteosbs;

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS hhva_matteosbs;
USE hhva_matteosbs;
Here is the beginning of my table